# Can I serve up a local Javascript file through an ASP.Net WebAPI method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

My previous post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999475/can-i-use-token-authentication-with-iis-8

mentioned that I was having difficult getting IIS to authenticate a user and serve a Javascript file.

This leads me to wonder if I can serve up a local Javascript file through a WebAPI method that is protected with

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Can someone tell me if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the response from the MVC WebApi and call `eval` function with the parameter as responsed script

```
$.get("/api/[ControllarName]", function(scriptResponse){
    eval(scriptResponse);
});
```